# Cómo eliminar una clase de mi elemento?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de eliminar la clase 'active' de mi carrusel pero no estoy pudiendo hacerlo.

Cuando click en la X del modal, llama a la función `CloseModal()` que sirve principalmente para hacer un `display = "none"` al modal

```
function CloseModal() {
    let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    let carouselItem = document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-item active");
    carouselItem.className.remove('active');
    modal.style.display = "none";    
}
```

El problema es que no se está detectando  `carouselItem.className.remove('active');` o `carouselItem.classList.remove('active');`:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'remove')

Cómo puedo hacerlo?

HTML:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="CloseModal()" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="C_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-touch="false" data-bs-interval="false">
                    <div id="Entrega_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" class="carousel-inner">
                        <!-- IMAGENES -->
                        @{
                            int cont2 = 0;
                            string img2 = "";
                        }
                        @foreach (var pd in Model)
                        {
                            if (img2 != pd.getImagenes().ToString())
                            {
                                <div class="carousel-item" id="carousel-item_@cont2">
                                    <form action="DescargarImagenIndividual" class="mb-3 position-relative">
                                        <button type="submit" id="btnDescargarImagen" class="btn btn-primary mt-3" value="@pd.getImagenes()" name="imagenSelec">
                                            <i class="fa fa-download mx-2"></i>Descargar Imágen
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" id="img01_@cont2" src="@pd.getImagenes()" onclick="GetImagenes(@pd.getNumeroEntrega(),this)" data-img-mostrar="@cont2" />
                                </div>
                            }
                            cont2++;
                            img2 = pd.getImagenes();
                        }
                    </div>
                    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#C_@Model.First().getNumeroEntrega()" data-bs-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: intentaste llamarla por el id?

Comment: El tema es que estoy tratando de remover el `div` que tenga la clase `active`, como obtengo ese `div` si no es buscando directamente al que lo tenga?

Comment: es classList.remove

Comment: Exacto, pero cómo busco al `div` tiene `active` en su clase? No todos lo tienen, solo 1

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("carousel-item active")[0];

Comment: getElement**s**ByClassName: como dice el propio nombre de la función, te devuelve una colección de elementos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getElementsByClassName de devuelve una especie de array de elementos, NO un solo elemento por eso no tiene la propiedad classList.remove

Luego debes ocupar classList.remove en lugar de className.remove

```
function CloseModal() {
    let modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    let carouselItem = document.querySelector(".carousel-item.active");
    carouselItem.classList.remove('active');
    modal.style.display = "none";    
}
```

Comment: Probé tu código pero me dice lo siguiente: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')`

Comment: @BilbitBolson Pero el carrousel está en el modal?

Comment: @BilbitBolson Prueba ahora

Comment: Sip, el carrusel está dentro del modal, ahora dejo el html

Comment: Ahora funciona de 10, gracias!